# Setting decimal places in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: significant-digits

In BlueSky Statistics, how can I control the number of decimal places used to display the results of the analysis? It's showing four value after the decimal place and I would like it to round off after two.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of decimal places displayed by clicking on the top level menu item "Tools" and selecting "Tools> Configuration settings", then navigate to the "Others" tab and you will see the option to change the number of decimal digits. The default is 4.